# Spring Boot - Transform response object/json - Flatten Array List of objects to DAO

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I am creating an inventory management system. An inward inventory will be a collection of products and respective quantities.So, one to many between InwardInventory and InwardOutwardList.

```
public class InwardOutwardList extends ReusableFields
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long entryid;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="productId",nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    Product product;

    Double quantity;
//getter setter
}
```

Inward Inventory

```
public class InwardInventory extends ReusableFields implements Cloneable
{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="inwardid")
    Long inwardid;
    @NonNull
    String vehicleNo;
    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "inwardinventory_entry", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "inwardid", referencedColumnName = "inwardid") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "entryId", referencedColumnName = "entryId") })
    Set<InwardOutwardList> inwardOutwardList = new HashSet<>();;
    

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="warehouse_id",nullable=false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    Warehouse warehouse;
```

So, when I fetch a single inward inventory having two products iron and cement , I receive data as nested jsons like below

```
[{
  "inwardid": 19497,
  "vehicleNo": "TRUCK",
  "inwardOutwardList": [
    {
      "entryid": 19499,
      "product": {
        "productName": "Cement"
      },
      "quantity": 100
    },
    {
      "entryid": 19500,
      "product": {
        "productName": "Iron"
      },
      "quantity": 10
    }
  ],
  "warehouse": {
    "warehouseName": "war2"
  },
  "supplier": {
    "name": "Bright Traders"
  }
}]
```

Now, I want to export it into csv. So, I need to flatten it to have only one level like below

```
[
  {
    "inwardid": 19497,
    "vehicleNo": "TRUCK",
    "productName": "Cement",
    "quantity": 100,
    "warehouseName": "war2"
  },
  {
    "inwardid": 19497,
    "vehicleNo": "TRUCK",
    "productName": "Iron",
    "quantity": 10,
    "warehouseName": "war2"
  }
]
```

I wrote simple nested for-each iterations and it is doing its job

```
private List<InwardInventoryExportFullDAO> transformStructure(List<InwardInventory> iiDataList) 
    {
        List<InwardInventoryExportFullDAO> data = new ArrayList<InwardInventoryExportFullDAO>();
        for(InwardInventory iiData:iiDataList)
        {
            for(InwardOutwardList ioList:iiData.getInwardOutwardList())
            {
                InwardInventoryExportFullDAO tempExportData = new InwardInventoryExportFullDAO();
                tempExportData.setWarehouse(iiData.getWarehouse().getWarehouseName());
                tempExportData.setVehicleNo(iiData.getVehicleNo());
                tempExportData.setQuantity(ioList.getQuantity());
                tempExportData.setProductName(ioList.getProduct().getProductName());
                data.add(tempExportData);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

But I do not feel it is an optimal solution if amount of inwardinventory records shoot up. The other option I see is using parallel streams or json mappers. But I am not sure which would be the best and optimal solution to achieve this. No of expected records to be exported excel are around 10k.

Nested Loops that I already written is taking ~5 seconds for 2k records. So, it may take 30+ seconds in future when load increases. So, looking for best optimal solution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: For CSV what library you are using ?

Comment: Plan is to send this as Json to fronend. Frontend will do the export

Comment: To flatten a nested Json you can write a custom deserializer and map all Json fields to a flat object.

Comment: @KevKosDev. I tried doing that. But the problem I faced was one to many mapping. I need 2 fields from parent object and two fields from child object lists. Parent's fields should be repeated for each child.  So, it is kind of cross join between parent and child. I was not able to figure out how to achieve that.

Comment: Tha's a bad idea since frontend need to process again and your current solution is much efficient I think, some minor modification can be done like use constructor/builder for DTO and for 2k record 5 sec maybe something else takes time. And for 10k data it's should  take maximum 1s to process it.

Comment: @Eklavya Thanks a lot for feedback about efficiency. I was in impression that using foreach loop will increase complexity. So, was looking for better solution. Regarding csv - Thanks you. I will rethink about it and may be I will send csv in response directly.

Comment: @Eklavya Do you think using parallel streams will improve this further. I mean which is more efficient between parallel stream and for each. I researched on google but was not able to find any concrete answer

Comment: I normally used parallelStream when data is bigger than 10k. You can try using `parallelStream() .forEach( ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a custom serializer

```
@Component
public class InwardExportSerializer extends StdSerializer<InwardInventory> 
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected InwardExportSerializer(Class<InwardInventory> t) 
    {
        super(t);
    }
    protected InwardExportSerializer() 
    {
        this(null);
    }
    @Override
    public void serialize(InwardInventory value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException 
    {
        for(InwardOutwardList ioList:value.getInwardOutwardList())
        {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeNumberField("inwardid", value.getInwardid());
            gen.writeStringField("productname",ioList.getProduct().getProductName() );
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
        
    }
        
}
```

Comment: Then you get List of List and convert it again in sigle List right ?  Is perpormance improved ?

Comment: Not actually. I tested for 3k records and performance is almost same. Will check again later with a bigger data set to check exact impact on performance.

Comment: I expect that will be same ! And now you are handling more data using your code adding extra field I think .

Comment: @Eklavya Actually Yes. I posted this answer only because if someone has similar problem, they have something to review. But in my case, using for each loop and iterating over entity data set and creating DAO seems better solution. In case of serializer, I am controlling creation of response json, so if I have to change name of field, I have to keep in mind to change it in serializer as well. So, this is burden. more over, performance is not improved through serializer. So, like you mentioned in your very initial comment, iterating over entity list seems better option.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom `JsonDeserializer` and extract nested Json fields into a flat pojo. Looks something like this:

```
public class Test extends JsonDeserializer<List<InventoryItem>> {

   private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   private final ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<InventoryItem>>() {});

    @Override
    public List<InventoryItem> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        String inwardId = node.get("inwardId").textValue();

        List<InventoryItem> foo = reader.readValue(node.get("inwardOutwardList"));

        foo.forEach(o -> o.setInwardId(inwardId));

        return foo;
    }
}
```

First you unpack the id from the root object, then deserialize the items and set the root id on each item.

Comment: I created a customer serializer as mentioned by you. and added annotatio to InwardInventory

@JsonDeserialize(using = InwardExportDeSerializer.class)
public class InwardInventory

But when execute. This serializer is not being invoked. Any idea why?